# Ontario HST: How to calculate new homebuyer's HST housing rebate?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, first-time-home-buyer, rebate

I'm buying a home from a develpoer, and I qualify for the first time homebuyer rebate. I'm wondering how Ontario's HST rebate for first time homebuyers is calculated.

The paragraph below is taken from http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/notices/hst/02.html and I thought I'd check with you financial gurus, because its not entirely clear.

> The effect of the enhanced rebate
>   would be to apply the provincial
>   portion of the single sales tax at a
>   rate of two per cent on the first
>   $400,000 of the purchase price of a
>   new home and at a rate of eight per
>   cent on the portion above $400,000.
>   The rebate would be calculated as 75
>   per cent of the provincial portion of
>   the single sales tax payable on the
>   purchase of a new home, up to a
>   maximum rebate of $24,000.

What exactly is the 'provincial portion'? Is it the old PST? (8% of purchase price)?

So does that mean if I'm buying a place for $300,000 before taxes, the rebate would be

> 0.75 x 0.08 x $300,000 (to a max of $24,000) = $18,000 rebate ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Your calculations are right, the rebate is 6% of your purchase price. Which is $18,000

Long answer: HST will not affect new home prices below $400K.  Which is confirmed by the 2nd paragraph under the Enhanced New Housing Rebate heading

> The new housing rebate would be enhanced so that new homes purchased as primary residences across all price ranges would qualify for a rebate of up to $24,000, while continuing to ensure that, on average, **new homes priced up to $400,000 would not be subject to additional tax compared to the retail sales tax (RST) currently embedded in the price of new homes.**

So there will be no extra taxes compared to when you purchase it now versus pre-HST in June 31, 2010.  However, at the time of sale, you'll still pay the tax of 300K * 0.13 = 39K but get a rebate when you file your taxes of 300K * 0.06 = 18K